# regsvr32 on COM dll x64 debug fails and can't get details on this

Tags: c++, debugging, dll, 64-bit, regsvr32

I have a COM dll output from my VS project that works ok for 32 bit release&debug, works ok for 64 bit release, but fails to register for 64 bit debug.

It fails with the following error:

> The module "(...).dll" failed to load.
>
> Make sure the binary is stored
>   at the specified path or debug it to check for problems with the
>   binary or dependent .DLL files.
>
> The specified module could not be
>   found.

- Already installed SP1 for VS2008 (fixed some lacking dependencies)
- %windir%/system32/regsvr32 or %windir%/sysWOW64/regsvr32 fails
- event viewer doesn't show up anything related (namely application error)
- SxsTrace doesn't catch anything:

  - sxstrace trace -logfile:sxstrace.etl
  - do the regsvr32
  - sxstrace parse -logfile:sxstrace.etl -outfile:sxstrace.txt
  - check sxstrace.txt
- dependency walker doesn't show any missing dependency (the missing ones are exactly the same to the release dll) AND there is no difference between the 64bit-release and the 64bit-debug dependencies (unless some debug dependencies instead of the release ones)

How do I retrieve more information on the error?

Already lost some days on this, going to weeks...!

Comment: Do not use Depends anymore, it hasn't been maintained in a long time and is unfit to find dependencies on modern executables.  Use SysInternals' Process Monitor instead.  You'll see regsvr32.exe searching for a DLL and not finding it.  Don't store DLLs in a c:\windows directory, the file system redirector is going to cause trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- As Hans Passant pointed out, we can use Process Monitor and filter regsvr32 activity
- We can also run dependency walker profile by opening regsvr32.exe and profiling for our dll (http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/252604-Cant-Register-a-dll-in-Vista-Home-Premium-registers-fine-in-XP/f2ea273334e74839962f9dea0152f420)